# Passing $(this) in setTimeout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I pass $(this) as a parameter in the setTimeout function (method?)?
Here's what I'm doing so far, which is working:

```
var Variables = {};
Variables.ResizeTimer = false;
Variables.$obj = null;

$('.draggable').resize(function() {
    if (Variables.ResizeTimer !== false) { 
        clearTimeout(Variables.ResizeTimer);
    }
    Variables.$obj = $(this);
    Variables.ResizeTimer = setTimeout(mySizer,
        1000
    );
});
```

Comment: Do you mean "how do I pass `$(this)` as a parameter to `mySizer`?" in this example?

Comment: Yes.  setTimeout expects the function to be within quotes if I add a parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
    Variables.$obj = $(this);
    Variables.ResizeTimer = setTimeout(
         function(){
             mySizer(Variables.$obj);
         },
         1000
    );
```

From [MPD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364913/mpd):

To elaborate on this, read up on Javascript closures

Comment: $(this) in this closure would not be what he needs. this is going to be the global object === window.

Comment: This is when I wish jQuery would include a proper binding function as opposed to its miserable `.proxy`.  In prototype the answer is cleaner: `setTimeout(mySizer.bind(null, $(this)), 1000);`.  If you do this a lot, I suggest ripping prototype's `Function.prototype.bind`

Answer (score 6):

Since `Variables` looks global you can use it inside the `mySizer` routine. If you don't want to have global variables you can create a [closure](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/):

```
$('.draggable').resize(function() {
    if (Variables.ResizeTimer !== false) { 
        clearTimeout(Variables.ResizeTimer);
    }
    var $this = $(this);
    Variables.ResizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        mySizer($this);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since no one has mentioned it yet: if you need `$(this)` only to do something effect-related, you might get away with just using the `delay` function instead of `setTimeout`.

```
$('#some_element').click(function() {

    $(this).delay(2000).fadeIn(); // After 2 seconds, start a fade-in
}
```

It is also possible to add a function call (for example) to `fadeIn`. This being useful really depends on your specific use-case though, but it might make things a lot easier if it works for your situation.

Hope this will be helpful to someone...

Comment: I had not heard of delay. Thank you. This question is from 2011, and I have since learned to .bind variables or place them in a larger scope.